# sed regex match first occurrence

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed, non-greedy

I have the following String:

```
<div class="downloadlist" id="Mactopia_Office2011"><p><a depEvents="DynamicDownloadsLinkClick[url|downloads?pid=Mactopia_Office2011&amp;fid=78B06C3D-0158-4344-8A8B-5FB822CD44D8#viewer|prodID|Mactopia_Office2011]" id="78B06C3D-0158-4344-8A8B-5FB822CD44D8" class="download_link" href="&#xD;&#xA;                          ?pid=Mactopia_Office2011&amp;fid=78B06C3D-0158-4344-8A8B-5FB822CD44D8#viewer&#xD;&#xA;                        ">Microsoft Office für Mac 2011 14.4.1-Update <span class="link_arrow">&gt;</span></a></p><p><a depEvents="DynamicDownloadsLinkClick[url|downloads?pid=Mactopia_Office2011&amp;fid=F7B8C82F-71FF-4675-8924-DAB652BA6603#viewer|prodID|Mactopia_Office2011]" id="F7B8C82F-71FF-4675-8924-DAB652BA6603" class="download_link" href="&#xD;&#xA;                          ?pid=Mactopia_Office2011&amp;fid=F7B8C82F-71FF-4675-8924-DAB652BA6603#viewer&#xD;&#xA;                        ">Microsoft Office für Mac 2011 14.3.9-Update <span class="link_arrow">&gt;</span></a></p><p><a depEvents="DynamicDownloadsLinkClick[url|downloads?pid=Mactopia_Office2011&amp;fid=3BEDF6DC-1464-4D17-A5BB-C90F8FEF567C#viewer|prodID|Mactopia_Office2011]" id="3BEDF6DC-1464-4D17-A5BB-C90F8FEF567C" class="download_link" href="&#xD;&#xA;                          ?pid=Mactopia_Office2011&amp;fid=3BEDF6DC-1464-4D17-A5BB-C90F8FEF567C#viewer&#xD;&#xA;                        ">Microsoft Office für Mac 2011 14.3.8-Update <span class="link_arrow">&gt;</span></a></p><p><a depEvents="DynamicDownloadsLinkClick[url|downloads?pid=Mactopia_Office2011&amp;fid=3445FBDC-E092-4530-BF31-D60CECD53AB8#viewer|prodID|Mactopia_Office2011]" id="3445FBDC-E092-4530-BF31-D60CECD53AB8" class="download_link" href="&#xD;&#xA;                          ?pid=Mactopia_Office2011&amp;fid=3445FBDC-E092-4530-BF31-D60CECD53AB8#viewer&#xD;&#xA;                        ">Microsoft Office für Mac 2011 14.3.7-Update <span class="link_arrow">&gt;</span></a></p><p><a depEvents="DynamicDownloadsLinkClick[url|downloads?pid=Mactopia_Office2011&amp;fid=EF1E612F-D8E3-4628-9FE4-AD136F0DEBD3#viewer|prodID|Mactopia_Office2011]" id="EF1E612F-D8E3-4628-9FE4-AD136F0DEBD3" class="download_link" href="&#xD;&#xA;                          ?pid=Mactopia_Office2011&amp;fid=EF1E612F-D8E3-4628-9FE4-AD136F0DEBD3#viewer&#xD;&#xA;                        ">
```

I'm trying to match this part: "Microsoft Office für Mac 2011 14.4.1-Update" using the following sed command: `s/^.*Microsoft Office f.r Mac 2011 \([^ ]*\)-Update.*$/\1/`
Unfortunately the output is 14.3.7 (so the last occurrence) how can I make it stop after the first occurance, considering that using `*?` for the non-greedy matching didn't help?

Comment: There _will_ be a way to parse this "string" using `sed` but it's clearly HTML. Have you considered parsing it as such? What languages would you be interested in using?

Comment: @TomFenech He is using sed.

Comment: @Taemyr I can see that. I am suggesting that it would be better to use a language with in-built capabilities to parse HTML, as the solution will be a lot cleaner and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two susbstitution commands, the first one to remove all characters after the first occurance, and the second one to remove all the leading characters:

```
sed 's/\(Microsoft Office f.r Mac 2011 \([^ ]*\)-Update\).*$/\1/; s/^.*>//' infile
```

It yields:

```
Microsoft Office für Mac 2011 14.4.1-Update
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not too tied to `sed`, you could also do

```
perl -pne 's/.*?(Microsoft Office.*?Update).*/$1/' file
```

or

```
grep -oP 'Microsoft Office.*?Update' file | head -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl has support for non-greedy regexes, so you could do this:

```
perl -pe 's|.*?(Microsoft Office f.+?r Mac 2011 \S+-Update).*|$1|' string
```

which gives you:

```
Microsoft Office für Mac 2011 14.4.1-Update
```

I changed the `.` in `f.r` to `.+?` so that when "ü" counts as more than one character it still works. I also made use of the `\S` (non-whitespace) character class.

Answer (score 1):

You can just grab the first data from the string using `awk` and you get:

```
awk -F " &" '{gsub(/<[^>]*>/,"");$1=$1;print $1;exit}' file
Microsoft Office für Mac 2011 14.4.1-Update
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this command also if there are only four strings (`Microsoft Office für Mac 2011 14.4.1-Update`) present on that line,

```
sed -rn 's/^.*[ ]+\">([^<]*)<.*[ ]+\">([^<]*)<.*[ ]+\">([^<]*)<.*[ ]+\">([^<]*)<.*$/\1/p' file.txt
```

Output:

```
Microsoft Office für Mac 2011 14.4.1-Update
```